# Magento : How do I set the set the cart price?

Tags: php, magento

I am a newbie to Magento Community Edition.
It might be a little thing but don’t know how to do that.

I want to set the cart price to cartprice * 5?
Example - if the cart items weight is greater then 10kg then set cartprice to (10 * 5).

Comment: In Magento admin go to Promtion -> ShoppingCart Price rules -> new rule - > Condition. Here we can get "TotalWeight" as cart attribute while defining condition.

Comment: ^^This should be an answer^^

Comment: Magento shopping cart price rules is only for discounts OR you can say it can subtracts the amount but not be able to multiply the amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by event observer.

```
  <checkout_cart_product_update_after>
    <observers>
        <update_price_edit_save_product>
        <class>ABC_MModule_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>cartUpdatePrice</method>
        </update_price_save_product>
    </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
```

in Observer class define this function, and do the implementation accordinly to set the price by item.

```
  public function cartUpdatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs){


    // Get the quote item
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        // Ensure we have the parent item, if it has one
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );



    //hidden filed from detail page


            $item->setCustomPrice($new_price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own module using event observers to accomplish this. First define a store config value for weight and how many times it should be increased i.e. 10kgs and 5 times in your requirement.

Using event **checkout_cart_product_update_after** you can call your observer function and include below code in that function

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
}

if($weight > Mage::getStoreConfig('weight'))){
$weight = $weight * Mage::getStoreConfig('number of times you want to increase)
}
return $weight;
```